# Listen to outgoing http/https requests in GoLang

Tags: web, go, request

I'm trying to make a GoLang program, that logs every outgoing http/https request when it runs on the computer, for example, when it's running it on my computer, when I open a browser and open http://example.com, it logs it.
An appreciated extra would be a way to redirect some unwanted website requests (like a parental control)

I've been trying and looking all around and it seems that all the examples out there consider the computer where the Go exe is running as a server.. That's not what I want

Thank you very much

Comment: this was cross-posted at: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/lgMQFn2INaQ/discussion

Answer (score 1):

Techniques for "getting every request" off a computer will vary a bit if your intent is to trap things that don't use common HTTP proxy settings (and things get a bit weird if [SSL/TLS is involved](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/8145), which on the modern Internet it almost assuredly is).  So let's ignore the complications of trying to actually get an unencrypted channel to MitM...

Assuming you're writing a simple HTTP proxy at first and expanding on that, try [GoProxy](https://github.com/elazarl/goproxy).  It has a good list of examples and a decent feature list.